# goBack() con react navigator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

tengo una duda tecnica. Estoy aprendiendo React Native y Tengo esta pantalla:

```
type ScannerProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Scanner">;
export const Scanner= ({navigation} : ScannerProps) =>{
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Camera 
            style={cameraStyle.camera}
            CameraType={CameraType.Back}
            scanBarcode={true}
            onReadCode={
                async (data: any) => {
                  console.log("escaneando....")
                  try {
                      const informacionEquipo : infoequipo = await getInfoEquipo(data.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)  
                      navigation.navigate("Detalles", {
                          eiDescripcion: informacionEquipo.ei_descripcion,
                          eiNroSerie: informacionEquipo.ei_nro_serie,
                          eiObservacion: informacionEquipo.ei_observacion,
                          eiCiEmpleado: informacionEquipo.ei_ci_empleado,
                      })
                  } catch (error : any) {
                    navigation.navigate("Principal")
                    Alert.alert(
                        error.title,
                        error.message,
                        [{
                            text : "Ok",
                            style: "destructive",
                        }]
                    )  
                    return;                   
                  }              
                }
            }
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Y cuando escanea correctamente un codigo me lleva a la pantalla de detalles:

```
type DetallesProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Detalles'>;
export const Detalles = ( {navigation, route} : DetallesProps ) =>{
    const descripcion = route.params.eiDescripcion
    const nroSerie = route.params.eiNroSerie
    const observacion = route.params.eiObservacion
    const empleado = route.params.eiCiEmpleado
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={containerStyle.mainContainer}>
            <View style={[containerStyle.row]}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={fontStyle.tituloUno}>
                        Informacion del Equipo
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={[containerStyle.row]}>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "30%"}]}>
                    <Text>Descripcion: </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "70%"}]}>
                    <Text>{descripcion}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={[containerStyle.row]}>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "30%"}]}>
                    <Text>Nro de Serie: </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "70%"}]}>
                    <Text>{nroSerie}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={[containerStyle.row]}>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "30%"}]}>
                    <Text>Observacion: </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "70%"}]}>
                    <Text>{observacion}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={[containerStyle.row]}>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "30%"}]}>
                    <Text>Empleado asignado: </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[containerStyle.column, {width: "70%"}]}>
                    <Text>{empleado}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Mi problema, y ahí va mi pregunta, naturalmente cuando se redirige a la pantalla de detalles, en el encabezado existe un botón para volver a la pantalla anterior. Que en este caso volveria a la pantalla del Escaner. Cuando regresa a la pantalla para escanear, mi escaner ya no hace nada, ya no escanea, ya no hace nada y tengo que volver una vez mas a Home para volver a darle a Escanear para que vuelva a funcionar, alguien me podria decir como funciona ese boton y porque ya no hace nada? Entiendo que es algo como que la pantalla no se inicializa otra vez al volver o eso creo, porfa me explican que puedo hacer o como programo ese boton automatico para que al volver escanee sin problema. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, agrega el código del botón, dices que esta en el encabezado